# (Done) Reopen "Joel Test equivalent for a high-performing digital marketing teams?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

Please consider reopening [Joel Test equivalent for a high-performing digital marketing teams?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/112894)
This question was edited to make it specific to a particular field, as was suggested in the comments. Answers to this question could be very useful for people working in the particular industry mentioned.

Comment: Is this a workplace question or a domain-specific question? I don't have an opinion, just wondering what people think. Does it belong on Workplace, or a marketing-specific forum?

Comment: Giving the volume of software engineering related questions which stay open on this site, allowing questions about other domains would provide some balance.

Comment: I see questions about KPI's are on topic here, this is kind of like a KPI for the employer.

Comment: @MackM, KPIs compare performance of particular metrics again expected goals. Joel's Test is a set of binary questions about practices within a company. It is more like maturity or capability model. You may well make the same argument about maturity models as you do about KPIs, i.e. they are in-scope.

Comment: *"Answers to this question could be very useful for people working in the particular industry mentioned."* - so they can spare the effort to Google it out? I am torn about the reopening of that post, as even though it could prove useful to other domains, it can well be answered by googling around a bit...

Comment: @DarkCygnus, On this site questions are regularly closed because there require answers based on opinion. That only leaves questions which have answers based in facts, i.e. answers that can be found using Google.

Comment: @gwp I suggest you take a read at [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). Not all subjective questions are off-topic.

Comment: @DarkCygnus, I would love to post my text as an answer but alas I can't so I did my best to help the questioner.

Comment: @DarkCygnus, "Not all subjective questions are off-topic." I totally agree. It’s a pity that many great subjective questions on this site are closed.

Comment: @gwp It's good you tried to help. Although I suggest that you don't make a habit of using comments for that in the future :) comment-answers are really a thing the Community doesn't like much. And yes, many users need to take a read at that Blog post :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78005/discussion-between-gwp-and-darkcygnus).

Comment: I have voted to reopen. If the question was "what is a simple test to measure the quality of a software development team?", we would have jumped over each other to write about the Joel Test and a bunch of other tests. I don't see how this question is any different. We also routinely answer questions that can be answered by an internet search engine (especially legal questions), so that isn't a good disqualification criterion either. Remember a question isn't off-topic just because the answer is obvious to us or it is available elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Casted the 5th and final vote to reopen. Perhaps now will be a good time to move the comment-answer into a proper answer of it's own (although the commenter seems to have disassociated their account or something...)